# display mysql columns which has only not null or blank in table

Tags: mysql

let's say I have a table like this:

```
╔════╦══════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦═════╗
║ id ║ name ║ h1 ║ h2 ║ h3 ║ h4 ║ h5 ║ h6 ║ h7 ║ h8 ║ h9 ║ h10 ║
╠════╬══════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ x    ║    ║    ║    ║    ║  1 ║    ║  1 ║    ║    ║     ║
╚════╩══════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩═════╝
```

I want to display mysql columns with no nulls or blank in table like this:

```
╔════╦══════╦════╦════╗
║ id ║ name ║ h5 ║ h7 ║
╠════╬══════╬════╬════╣
║  1 ║ x    ║  1 ║  1 ║
╚════╩══════╩════╩════╝
```

Please let us know is it possible?

Comment: Avoid if possible. Otherwise there are duplicates if you search for `pivot table`.

Comment: Though you pivot the table, how can you select only not null not blank columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't. Handle the blanks in the application layer.